# Stop Cordova based app clearing cache / temp files on update

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm not too familiar with plain cordova based apps (i've only worked with ionic), but i'm having an issue with an app and its images when updating.

Heres the steps to explain the problem

1. Install app and start to use it
2. Use the app to take photos using [cordova camera plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/) and [cordova plugin file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)
3. Update the app via the app store
4. Use the app to take more photos
5. Sync all data up to a Laravel 5 application

What happens here when the app is synced up, is that all of the images that were taken after the update, upload properly, but all of the photos taken before the update do not (even though the thumbnails in the app still show for the photos taken before the update).

Is there any way to retrieve the photos from the cache? Or stop the app from clearing any sort of files when it updates?

As stated i'm new to this (i've inherited the app i'm trying to fix), so if anyone could explain what could possibly be going wrong, or how to fix it that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have to provide more details on your code, because I've never heared abour any cache cleared when updating cordova apps (as long as the updated app uses the same signature). So I suspect the issue may come from your code rather than from cordova.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're storing your files in the cacheDirectory folder?

In that case it's not cleared by cordova when you update your app but by Android whenever it decides it would be a good idea.

I suggest you have a look at [the Android file system Layout array in the Cordova file plugin documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#android-file-system-layout) to find a better place to store your files.